# Span new line span

Tags: html, css, whitespace

```
<span>A</span>
<span>V</span>
```

Causes a space between these letters, how is this calculated excatly? As oppose to

```
<span>A</span><span>V</span>
```

Comment: Because there's a `\n` or `\r\n` between, which is `whitespace`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whitespace between inline elements is compressed (or converted if it's something other than spaces) to a single space and displayed.

The [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html) has more information:

> This layout may involve putting space between words (called inter-word space), but conventions for inter-word space vary from script to script. For example, in Latin scripts, inter-word space is typically rendered as an ASCII space (`&#x0020;`).

Comment: Can you link to some documentation regarding this? I'm curious to see how this works.

Comment: I don't know, but 'A &nbsp V' is not the same as span-newline-span, at least it doesn't use the same length.

Comment: @user1477535 But `A \n\n\t     V` would render as `A V`. `&nbsp;` adds an *additional* character to existing whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a class on span which will force the second span to new line
and the **CSS** as

```
 .spanClass 
 {
    display:block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

*span* is an inline element like the simple text so it follow the same style rules. When you write on a new line the rendering put a white space.

```
A
B
```

will become "A B", with a whitespace between A and B. This happen also with *strong* or *em*