# Unindented code with spans has strange wrapping behavior

Tags: css

I have text in spans which is wrapping strangely. Ive worked out that if I indent the html it fixed the issue.

This is fine:

```
<div class="value">
    <span>56959 bqCYXFYS</span>
    <span>MBIaLbJm</span>
    <span>SW6 6PN</span>
</div>
```

This is not:

```
<div class="value"><span>56959 bqCYXFYS</span><span>MBIaLbJm</span><span>SW6 6PN</span></div>
```

This CSS is just for illustrative purposes:

```
.value {
    background: grey;
}
span:first-of-type {
    color: red;
}
span:nth-of-type(2) {
    color: green;
}
span:nth-of-type(3) {
    color: gold;
}
```

In the screenshots below ive manually shrunk div.value to make the text wrap. The top screenshots of the indented code is correct, and the 2nd screenshots of unindented code are wrapping in the strange way that I need to prevent.

How can I solve this with CSS only? I cant change the HTML structure at all.

[image]

Unindented code example: http://jsfiddle.net/67u7d/7/

Indented code example: http://jsfiddle.net/67u7d/6/

Comment: have a look at this answer to find out the (possible) reasons: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496720/span-new-line-span](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496720/span-new-line-span)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping occurs when there's whitspace, but since you do not have whitespace (even newline and tabs) between your spans, it's all one "word" that will not break.

As far as breaking, these are identical:

```
<div class="value"><span>56959 bqCYXFYS</span><span>MBIaLbJm</span><span>SW6 6PN</span></div>
<div class="value">56959 bqCYXFYSMBIaLbJmSW6 6PN</div>
```

To solve it and keep your spans as **true inline elements,** you can add a space after the spans using a `:after` pseudo element:

```
span:after {content:' ';}
```

Here's your new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/67u7d/9/

Comment: I cant change my html at all so I cant add any whitespacing.

Comment: @jdln Ah, i missed that. I've updated my answer with a solution that will add the space for you using CSS, without changing your HTML or the display property of your spans.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `display: inline-block` to your `span` tag, it will wrap correctly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/67u7d/8/ The entire span breaks onto the next line not just the last word in the span, so "SW6 6PN" breaks when just "6PN" should.